# What were the changes to philosophy after the second world war?

Tags: ethics, history-of-philosophy

I just want to know, like existentialism, what were the other theories in philosophy that changed due to the second world war and what new philosophical theories emerged due to the second world war.

Comment: I made an edit which you may roll back or continue editing. Welcome.

Comment: There is hardly anything really new in philosophy, but what started after the war, perhaps with the best of intentions, to read less into history, became almost the elimination of historical appreciation and understanding. This is my opinion and others may not share it.

Comment: Odds & Ends:  Anglo-American analytic philosophy came into full prominence. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_philosophy || see philosophical trajectory of Sidney Hook https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidney_Hook || Books on French Philosophy by Vincent Descombes; Maurice Friedman, "To Deny Our Nothingness: Contemporary Images of Man" 3rd ed. with new Preface and new Appendices Chicago: The University of Chicago Press, Phoenix Books, 1978, Reprinted as a Midway Book.

Comment: This a question for a history of philosophy book, or at least an encyclopedia article, not SE. All philosophical doctrines underwent changes after the war (not necessarily *due* to it). You need to narrow the scope: are you interested in changes to the existentialism specifically, changes directly attributable to the war itself...? For general information see [postmodernism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postmodernism) and [contemporary philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contemporary_philosophy).

Comment: Far too many changes to list here. If you include philosophy of AI, all this happened after WWII. All the philosophical objections to AI theory were developed after 1960. If you want to call computationalism a philosophical theory - and it's about the machine mind - founder Turing thought about related issued during WWII, and he used work he'd done before WWII, but he first published AI ideas in his 1947 Lecture on the ACE [Automatic Computing Engine] to the London Mathematical Society.